# Pdf for discrete vs continuous random variables.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

[image: Sorry for the screenshot. I took a picture of the notes butt it was of too high a quality to be uploaded here. Taking a screenshot of the photo lowered the quality enough ttyl8r be uploaded here.]

Definition 1
I understand that the probability distribution function for discrete variables is f(y)= P(Y=y).

Definition 2
Yet for continuous variables it's the derivative of the cumulative distribution function.

Ie: if I'm picking out a number between 0 and 2

By definition 1. The probability I pick 1 is zero. So f(1)=0

By definition 2 it's 1/2, because the cuff dugout the distribution would be a straight line from 0,0 to 2,1. With 1/2 gradient.

I'm confused that they're both called probability distribution functions yet they can give different functions.

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me. Where is Definition 1 and Definition 2?

Comment: Sorry. By definition 1 and 2 I meant the discrete and continuous definitions for pdf respectively

Comment: Discrete random variables have probability *mass* functions. Continuous random variables have probability *density* functions. For continuous random variables, the derivative of the cumulative distribution function is the probability density function. For discrete random variables, the cumulative distribution function is not (classically) differentiable at all, because it is not even continuous. The fundamental concept is really the cumulative distribution function, it is just easier to express certain particular things in terms of the probability mass function or probability density function.

Comment: I would say that your book is using confusing terminology by referring to $p(y)=P(Y=y)$ as a "pdf" (presumably thinking of the term "probability distribution function" which I have never seen used anywhere else). At any rate their usage is self-consistent because they say "probability distribution function" and "probability density function". They just happen to have the same abbreviation, which seems to be confusing you.

Comment: So my "definition 1" is actually the probability distribution function. While my "definition 2" was the probability density function?

Comment: That's right, at least in the terminology your book is using.